# How do I specify my own NER classifier in StanfordNLP coreference resolution tagging?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have trained my own NER classifier and now I want to use that in doing the coreference resolution. How do I do this? I tried this:

`java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators ner,coref -loadClassifier ./classifiers/my_classifier.ser.gz -coref.algorithm neural -file my_file.txt`

But it didn't work and error message: 

`java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL`

So it seems that it is still not using my NER classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have the custom model stored at:

```
/Users/stanfordnlphelp/custom_model.ser.gz
```

Then you want to add this option:

```
-ner.model /Users/stanfordnlphelp/custom_model.ser.gz
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Now it complains that it cannot find the tagger. (Should I ask this question in a new post?)    "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
 at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:470)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:789)"

Comment: Also remove the "-loadClassifier" portion.  You will not get the model not found error if you have the models jar in your CLASSPATH and you are running that command in the directory with those jars.  You are having some sort of issue with your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks! I have removed "-loadClassifier" portion. So I have downloaded the entire model and I am running from here: Documents/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31 .  I run this command: `java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,coref -ner.model aknowledgment/classifiers/wos-funding-top500k_highf_thresh_nosim.ser.gz -coref.algorithm statistical -file aknowledgment/test_data/test-funding.txt` still getting "annotator "coref" requires annotation "EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation""

Comment: Also, I wonder what would be the format of the input file here. Should it be sentences? I wonder if my using the same training data for the NER classifier would be the problem.

Comment: You need: -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref